# Parser: How to Turn a JavaScript String into One Line of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a parser for formatting JavaScript in a contextual format. First I want to be able to convert the input JavaScript into one line of JavaScript and then format the code based on my requirements.  This does not remove all of the enters or white space:

```
txt = $.trim(txt);
txt = txt.replace("\n", "");
```

How can I convert the text into one line?

Answer (score 8):

Use a regular expression with the "global" flag set:

```
txt.replace(/\n/g, "");
```

However, you should be careful about removing linebreaks in Javascript. You might break code that was depending on semicolon insertion. Why don't you use an off-the shelf parser like Esprima?

Comment: plus any comment using `//` would break everything

Answer (score 3):

Use :

- \s character that represents any space character (Carriage return, Line Feed, Tabs, Spaces, ...)
- the "greedy" g flag.

  var text = txt.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

Hope it helps

Comment: Added a quantifier to fix it.

Comment: "g" is from global flag, not "greedy". "+" is greedy.

Answer (score 0):

If the text comes from *some* operating systems, it may have the `\r\n` line ending, so it is worth removing both...

You should also use `/\r/g` this replaces ALL `\r`s not just the first one.

```
var noNewLines = txt.replace(/\r/g, "").replace(/\n/g, "");
```

You have to be pretty sure there are no single-line comments and that there are no missing semi-colons.

Comment: Here is an example of why you need to watch out for single-line comments... http://jsfiddle.net/m7jRz/

Answer (score -1):

You can try to minify your code, using something like https://javascript-minifier.com/ 
however this will also change your variable names